# Refresh div (jquery+asp.net mvc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I think the question is trival, however i can not find the solution. Im trying to refresh div automatically, for instance:

```
<div id="divToRefresh"> @(DateTime.Now)</div>
```

How can I do this in JQuery?

Comment: have a look at this. It will give you an idea : http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/working-with-jquery-ajax-api-on-asp-net-mvc-3-0-power-of-json-jquery-and-asp-net-mvc-partial-views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant refresh the div as you suggest. You need to load new content in, for your example this will work

```
$('#divToRefresh').html(now.format("dd/m/yy h:MM tt"))
```

The above method uses pure JavaScript. If you want to use .Net you can use JavaScript to launch a AJAX call to a JSON Action Reuslt.

```
public JsonResult GetDate()
{
    return Json(new { CurDate = DateTime.Now}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And your JQuery

```
$.getJSON('pathToActionResult', function(data) {
    $('#divToRefresh').html(data.CurDate)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple pure JavaScript solution to get you started.

http://jsfiddle.net/B7U2d/

Answer (score 0):

for very simple ajax situations like this, I like pjax http://pjax.heroku.com/